# TestNG Report is sending previous report

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have used this very simple code, and I have tried to send an emailable report under the @AfterSuite Annotation but **the problem is it is sending the old (previous) report**. Not the latest one. Note I have also tried thread.sleep under the email method.

```
package testOWC;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;

import java.awt.AWTException;

public class All_TestCases {
  
@SuppressWarnings({ })
@Test (priority =1)
public void RequiredFieldsOnly() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
  RequiredFieldsOnly.testCase();
}
  
@Test (priority =2)
public void Yourself() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
  Yourself.testCase();
  
}

@Test (priority =3)
public void Yourself_Representative() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
  Yourself_Representative.testCase();
  
}

@Test (priority =4)
public void Representative_YourselfNotConf() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
  Representative_YourselfNotConf.testCase();
  
}

@Test (priority =5)
public void Representative_YourselfConf() throws InterruptedException, IOException, AWTException {
  Representative_YourselfConf.testCase();
  
} 

@AfterSuite
public void email() throws MessagingException, InterruptedException {
  
  Email_Invoke.main(null);
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the code for sending email `Email_Invoke.main(null)`

Comment: Thank you for the response @NandanA.. The code is okay.. the thing is I need a way to run it after the Test Case has been executed. That is the issue.

Comment: Are you flushing the extent reports?

Comment: `ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports(ExtentReportsLocationFileName, true);`  and `extent.flush();` do this before sending report.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a report in the wrong place.
When you are running your tests with `maven` the report is generated in the `target` folder. When you are running with the `testng.xml` file the report is generated in the `test-output` folder. So I think after a run you are looking in the wrong place. Check it, please.

Comment: No...... report is attaching correctly. the issue is it is sending report which just previous to the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Report will be generated after the completion of all Hooks.

- @BeforeSuite
- @BeforeTest
- @BeforeClass
- @BeforeMethod
- @Test
- @AfterMethod
- @AfterClass
- @AfterTest
- @AfterSuite

Please write seperate program to send mail.

**Approach** :

1. Create .bat file
2. first command should be TestNG execution
3. Second command should be your mail program

**Sample bat file** :

> mvn test && java -jar zippingAndEmail.jar

Comment: I have tried bat file but the problem is report does not get generated if you are running test from cmd. It is necessary to execute the case from the IDE itself to generate the report bcoz TestNG is implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where the Report was not generated till the completion of the run. I solved it in the following way: the tests ran by Jenkins job (or by TFS agent an so on) and when the job was completed I had another Job collecting the archive and sending it to the mailing list.

Second option is to trigger the TestNg report yourself in the @After method, since the report is triggered only afterwards. this is something I didn't try myself but should be possible.